# Teamviewer on Jetson nano: CheckCPU: unknown architecture aarch64

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, teamviewer

I've installed teamviewer on Jetson nano following this instruction: [Tutorial TeamViewer 14 on Nvidia Jetson TX2](https://www.myzhar.com/blog/tutorials/teamviewer-14-on-nvidia-jetson-tx2/). It fails in two ways:

- if I launch it from command line, i get following output:

  ```
  Init...
  Error: CheckCPU: unknown architecture 'aarch64'
  ```
- if I connect to it after setting password through command line, it allows to enter login remotely, but after entering password it immediately disconnects.

I tried changing WaylandEnable /etc/gdm3/custom.conf, but it doesn't help. What else can I try?

Comment: ARM64 example hint https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/Linux/How-to-get-TeamViewer-working-on-ARM64/td-p/49322

Comment: hint is missing there, i already did apt -f install as you see from my link

Comment: Have you checked this too https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/Linux/unknown-architecture-aarch64/m-p/59974/highlight/true#M3560

Answer (score 1):

FTR I found this first and then saw the comment saying you check it out:

- [unknown architecture 'aarch64'](https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/Linux/unknown-architecture-aarch64/td-p/55938)

> I was able to solve this by adding aarch64 to the checks performed by
>   the start script. Navigate to where teamviewer is installed (for me
>   this was /opt/teamviewer). Navigate further to tv_bin/script. Open
>   tvw_main and find the section where it checks the architecture
>   (CheckCPU function). Where you see ( armv71 ), add aarch64, so the
>   line now reads ( armv71 | aarch64 ). Then try running it again (run
>   "teamviewer" from the terminal).

The solution didn't work for two other users though..